# I'm currently trying to do battleships with RMI and would like to transfer the playground to the other client, but it woudn't work

Tags: java, server, client, rmi, classcastexception

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Design.Playground cannot be cast to class java.rmi.Remote (Design.Playground is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.rmi.Remote is in module java.rmi of loader 'bootstrap')
at Game.Game$3.mouseClicked(Game.java:100)
```

The Server is Player 1.

The Client is Player 2.

Is it not possible to transfer the Playground to the Client?

```
package RMI;

import Design.*;
import Game.Game;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements BattleshipServer {

    private Playground p1 = new Playground();
    private Playground p2 = new Playground();
    private boolean hostTurn = true;
    private boolean winner = false;

    public Server() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        BattleshipServer server = new Server();
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        registry.rebind("BattleshipServer", server);
        System.out.println("Server ready");
        server.game(true);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean getHostTurn() {
        return hostTurn;
    }
    @Override
    public void changeHostTurn() {
        hostTurn = !hostTurn;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean getWinner() {
        return winner;
    }
    @Override
    public void changeWinner() {
        winner = true;
    }
    @Override
    public String game(boolean host) throws RemoteException {
        Game game = new Game(this);
        game.game(host);
        return "Yes";
    }
    @Override
    public Game getGame() throws RemoteException {
        return new Game(this);
    }
    @Override
    public Playground getPlayground(int p) throws RemoteException {
        if(p==1) return p1;
        if(p==2) return p2;
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void sendPlayground(Playground playground, int p) throws RemoteException {
        if(p==1) p1 = (Playground) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject((Remote) playground,1099);
        if(p==2) p2 = (Playground) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject((Remote) playground,1099);
    }
}
```

```
package RMI;

import Game.Game;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {
    private final BattleshipServer server;

    public Client(String ip, int port) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(ip,port);
        server = (BattleshipServer) registry.lookup("BattleshipServer");
    }
    public String method() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        Game game = server.getGame();
        game.game(false);
        //return server.game(false);
        return "";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        Client client = new Client("localhost", 1099);
        System.out.println(client.method());
    }
}
```

```
package RMI;

import Design.*;
import Game.Game;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface BattleshipServer extends Remote {
    String game(boolean host) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException;
    Game getGame() throws RemoteException;
    Playground getPlayground(int p) throws RemoteException;
    void sendPlayground(Playground playground, int p) throws RemoteException;
    boolean getHostTurn() throws RemoteException;
    void changeHostTurn() throws  RemoteException;
    boolean getWinner() throws RemoteException;
    void changeWinner() throws RemoteException;
}
```

```
package Game;

import Design.*;
import RMI.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class Game {

    private final Server server;

    public Game(Server server){
        this.server = server;
    }

    private int turn = 7;
    private boolean firstHit = true;
    private boolean hit = false;
    private final BattleshipFrame frame = new BattleshipFrame();

    //Playground erstellen und Schiffliste erstellen
    private Playground playground = new Playground();
    private Playground enemyPlayground = new Playground();

    public void game(boolean host) {

        frame.initialGUI(10, playground);
        frame.initialGUI(21, enemyPlayground);
        enemyPlayground.enabled(false);

        final int[] zaehler = {0};
        final int[] x1 = {0};
        final int[] y1 = {0};
        final int[] x2 = {0};
        final int[] y2 = {0};

        frame.getHostGameButton().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
        frame.getJoinGameButton().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < playground.getPlayground().length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < playground.getPlayground()[i].length; j++) {
                int finalI = i;
                int finalJ = j;
                playground.getPlayground()[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                        if(playground.getPlayground()[finalI][finalJ].isEnabled()) {
                            if (turn > -1) {
                                int size = 0;
                                if (turn == 7 || turn == 6) size = 4;
                                if (turn == 5 || turn == 4 || turn == 3) size = 3;
                                if (turn == 2 || turn == 1 || turn == 0) size = 2;

                                if (zaehler[0] == 0) {
                                    frame.setText("Server playground kopiert");
                                    frame.setText("Server playground kopiert");
                                    frame.setText("Server playground kopiert");
                                    frame.setText("Server playground kopiert");

                                    x1[0] = finalI;
                                    y1[0] = finalJ;
                                    playground.getPlayground()[finalI][finalJ].setEnabled(false);
                                    playground.changeButtons(finalI, finalJ, size, false);
                                }
                                if (zaehler[0] == 1) {
                                    x2[0] = finalI;
                                    y2[0] = finalJ;
                                }
                                zaehler[0]++;

                                if (zaehler[0] == 2) {
                                    placeShip(x1[0], y1[0], x2[0], y2[0], size);
                                    playground.changeButtons(finalI, finalJ, size, true);
                                    if (turn != 6 && turn != 3) playground.disableNotPlaceable(size);
                                    else playground.disableNotPlaceable(size - 1);
                                    zaehler[0] = 0;
                                    turn--;
                                    if(turn == -1) {
                                        enemyPlayground = enemyPlayground.copyPlayground(playground, 1);
                                        enemyPlayground.enabled(false);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (turn == -1) {
                                if (host && server.getHostTurn()) {
                                    try {
                                        server.sendPlayground(enemyPlayground, 1);
                                    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    server.changeHostTurn();
                                    turn--;
                                    System.out.println("Server playground kopiert");
                                } else if(!(host || server.getHostTurn())) {
                                    try {
                                        server.sendPlayground(enemyPlayground, 2);
                                    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    server.changeHostTurn();
                                    turn--;
                                    System.out.println("Client playground kopiert");
                                } else if(!host && server.getHostTurn()) System.out.println("Bitte auf Server warten");
                            } else if (turn == -2) {
                                if (host && server.getHostTurn()) {
                                    try {
                                        playground = playground.copyPlayground(server.getPlayground(2), 1);
                                        server.changeHostTurn();
                                        System.out.println("Client playground auf Server kopiert");
                                    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    turn--;
                                } else if(host && !server.getHostTurn()) System.out.println("Bitte auf Client warten");
                                else if (!(host || server.getHostTurn())) {
                                    try {
                                        playground = playground.copyPlayground(server.getPlayground(1), 1);
                                        server.changeHostTurn();
                                        System.out.println("Server playground auf Client kopiert");
                                    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    turn--;
                                } else if(!host && server.getHostTurn()) System.out.println("Bitte auf Server warten");
                                playground.enabled(true);
                            } else if (turn == -3) {
                                if (host && server.getHostTurn()) {
                                    if(server.getWinner()) {
                                        System.out.println("Du hast leider verloren!");
                                        turn = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                                    } else {
                                        try {
                                            server.sendPlayground(playground, 2);
                                        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        playground.getPlayground()[finalI][finalJ].setEnabled(false);
                                        hit(finalI, finalJ, playground);
                                    }
                                    if(firstHit && !hit) firstHit = false;
                                    else if(!firstHit){
                                        try {
                                            enemyPlayground = enemyPlayground.copyPlayground(server.getPlayground(1), 2);
                                        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if(hit) hit = false;
                                    else server.changeHostTurn();
                                } else if(host && !server.getHostTurn()) System.out.println("Bitte auf Client warten");
                                else if(!(host || server.getHostTurn())) {
                                    if(server.getWinner()) {
                                        System.out.println("Du hast leider verloren!");
                                        turn = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                                    } else {
                                        try {
                                            server.sendPlayground(playground, 1);
                                        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        playground.getPlayground()[finalI][finalJ].setEnabled(false);
                                        hit(finalI, finalJ, playground);
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        enemyPlayground = enemyPlayground.copyPlayground(server.getPlayground(2), 2);
                                    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    if(hit) hit = false;
                                    else server.changeHostTurn();
                                } else if(!host && server.getHostTurn()) System.out.println("Bitte auf Server warten");

                                enemyPlayground.enabled(false);
                                //if(!(host || server.getHostTurn()) || (host && server.getHostTurn()))
                                    playground.enabled((true));

                                if (playground.getShipList().isEmpty()) {
                                    turn = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                                    if(host) {
                                        System.out.println("HOST GEWONNEN");
                                        server.changeHostTurn();
                                        server.changeWinner();
                                        try {
                                            enemyPlayground = enemyPlayground.copyPlayground(server.getPlayground(1), 2);
                                        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("CLIENT GEWONNEN");
                                        server.changeHostTurn();
                                        server.changeWinner();
                                        try {
                                            enemyPlayground = enemyPlayground.copyPlayground(server.getPlayground(2), 2);
                                        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    public void placeShip(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int size) {
        int [][] pos = new int[2][size];
        boolean vertical = y1 - y2 != 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(!vertical && x2 > x1) {
                pos[0][i] = x1+i;
                pos[1][i] = y1;
                playground.getPlayground()[x1+i][y1].setEnabled(false);
                playground.getPlayground()[x1+i][y1].setBackground(playground.getShipColor());
            }
            if(!vertical && x1 > x2) {
                pos[0][i] = x1-i;
                pos[1][i] = y1;
                playground.getPlayground()[x1-i][y1].setEnabled(false);
                playground.getPlayground()[x1-i][y1].setBackground(playground.getShipColor());
            }
            if(vertical && y2 > y1) {
                pos[0][i] = x1;
                pos[1][i] = y1+i;
                playground.getPlayground()[x1][y1+i].setEnabled(false);
                playground.getPlayground()[x1][y1+i].setBackground(playground.getShipColor());
            }
            if(vertical && y1 > y2) {
                pos[0][i] = x1;
                pos[1][i] = y1-i;
                playground.getPlayground()[x1][y1-i].setEnabled(false);
                playground.getPlayground()[x1][y1-i].setBackground(playground.getShipColor());
            }
        }
        playground.getShipList().add(new Ship(size,pos));
    }
    public void shipDestroyed() {
        for (int i = 0; i < playground.getShipList().size(); i++) {
            boolean destroyed = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < playground.getShipList().get(i).getSize(); j++) {
                if (!playground.getPlayground()[playground.getShipList().get(i).getPos()[0][j]][playground.getShipList().get(i).getPos()[1][j]].getBackground().equals(Color.ORANGE)){
                    destroyed = false;
                }
            }
            if (destroyed){
                for (int j = 0; j < playground.getShipList().get(i).getSize(); j++) {
                    playground.getPlayground()[playground.getShipList().get(i).getPos()[0][j]][playground.getShipList().get(i).getPos()[1][j]].setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
                playground.getShipList().remove(i);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < playground.getPlayground().length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < playground.getPlayground()[i].length; j++) {
                if(playground.hasNeighbor(i,j,Color.RED) && !playground.getPlayground()[i][j].getBackground().equals(Color.RED)){
                        playground.getPlayground()[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                        playground.getPlayground()[i][j].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void hit(int x, int y, Playground playground) {
        for (Ship ship : playground.getShipList()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ship.getSize(); j++) {
                if (ship.getPos()[0][j] == x && ship.getPos()[1][j] == y) {
                    playground.getPlayground()[ship.getPos()[0][j]][ship.getPos()[1][j]].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                    hit = true;
                    shipDestroyed();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        playground.getPlayground()[x][y].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

```
package Design;

import Game.Ship;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Playground implements Serializable {

    private final JButton [][] playground = new JButton[10][10];
    private final List<Ship> shipList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Color waterColor = new Color(80, 150, 255);
    private final Color shipColor = new Color(0,0,0);

    public Playground(){
        for (int i = 0; i < playground.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < playground[i].length; j++) {
                playground[i][j] = new JButton();
                playground[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
                playground[i][j].setBackground(waterColor);
            }
        }
    }
    public JButton[][] getPlayground() {
        return playground;
    }

    public Color getShipColor(){
        return shipColor;
    }

    public List<Ship> getShipList(){
        return shipList;
    }

    public boolean hasNeighbor(int x, int y, Color color) {
        boolean hasNeighbor = false;
        try{
            if (playground[x+1][y].getBackground().equals(color)) {
                hasNeighbor = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
        try{
            if (playground[x+1][y+1].getBackground().equals(color)) {
                hasNeighbor = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
        try{
            if (playground[x+1][y-1].getBackground().equals(color)) {
                hasNeighbor = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
        try{
            if (playground[x][y+1].getBackground().equals(color)) {
                hasNeighbor = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
        try{
            if ( playground[x][y-1].getBackground().equals(color)) {
                hasNeighbor = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
        try{
            if (playground[x-1][y].getBackground().equals(color)) {
                hasNeighbor = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
        try{
            if (playground[x-1][y+1].getBackground().equals(color)) {
                hasNeighbor = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
        try{
            if (playground[x-1][y-1].getBackground().equals(color)) {
                hasNeighbor = true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
        return hasNeighbor;
    }
    public void changeButtons(int x, int y, int size, boolean change) {
        size--;
        for (int i = 0; i < playground.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < playground[i].length; j++) {
                if(change){
                    if(!playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(shipColor) && !hasNeighbor(i,j,shipColor)) {
                        playground[i][j].setBackground(waterColor);
                        playground[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    if(hasNeighbor(i,j,shipColor) && !playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(shipColor)) {
                        playground[i][j].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                        playground[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(!((i==x+size && j==y)|| (i==x-size && j==y) || (i==x && j==y+size) || (i==x && j==y-size)) && !playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(shipColor)) {
                            playground[i][j].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                            playground[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void disableNotPlaceable(int size) {
        size--;
        for (int i = 0; i < playground.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < playground[i].length; j++) {
                boolean placeable = false;
                try {
                    if (playground[i][j+size].getBackground().equals(waterColor) && playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(waterColor)) {
                        placeable = true;
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {
                }
                try {
                    if (playground[i][j-size].getBackground().equals(waterColor) && playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(waterColor)) {
                        placeable = true;
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {
                }
                try {
                    if (playground[i+size][j].getBackground().equals(waterColor) && playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(waterColor)) {
                        placeable = true;
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {
                }
                try {
                    if (playground[i-size][j].getBackground().equals(waterColor) && playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(waterColor)) {
                        placeable = true;
                    }
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {
                }
                if (!(placeable || playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(shipColor) || playground[i][j].getBackground().equals(Color.GRAY))) {
                    playground[i][j].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    playground[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void clear(){
        for (JButton[] jButtons : playground) {
            for (JButton jButton : jButtons) {
                jButton.setBackground(waterColor);
                jButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        for(int i=shipList.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
            shipList.remove(i);
        }
    }
    public Playground copyPlayground(Playground playground, int mode) {
        clear();
        for(int i=0;i<this.playground.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<this.playground[i].length;j++) {
                if(mode == 1) {
                    if(playground.getPlayground()[i][j].getBackground().equals(shipColor)) {
                        this.getPlayground()[i][j].setBackground(playground.getPlayground()[i][j].getBackground());
                    }
                } else if(mode == 2) this.getPlayground()[i][j].setBackground(playground.getPlayground()[i][j].getBackground());
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<playground.getShipList().size();i++) {
            if(playground.getShipList().size()>0) {
                this.getShipList().add(playground.getShipList().get(i));
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
    public void enabled(boolean enable){
        for (JButton[] jButtons : this.playground) {
            for (JButton jButton : jButtons) {
                if(jButton.getBackground().equals(waterColor) && enable) jButton.setEnabled(true);
                else if(!enable) jButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your playground be Serializable?

Comment: I could add it. But it wouldn't change the error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can't export an object that doesn't implement `Remote`, and exporting it doesn't constitute sending it to the client anyway. You need to return it as the result of a remote method.

Comment: @close-voters VTR. The problem in the question is trivial to spot if you know anything about RMI, and there is nothing missing from the question for that purpose. Please don't pile on with the close-votes to things you personally don't understand.